# How to convert string to command?

Tags: macros, xetex, strings

How can I run command by using string?

for example, I have created new command:

```
\newcommand\footn{\footnote}
```

Now, I don't want to use this command directly,

I want to use `@footn{*}` instead this: `\footn{*}`

I don't want to use `\catcode`, because by using it, I can't use `@` character normally in my text. I want to set `@` character active, only when it used by `footn` command. how can I do it? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Since the `\footnote` directive takes an argument, you may want to start by writing `\newcommand\footn[1]{\footnote{#1}}`. Incidentally, it would help if you provided some motivation for your preference for writing `@footn{...}` instead of `\footn{...}`. Is the backslash character maybe hard to reach on your keyboard?

Comment: Useful related (not duplicate but should read by anyone interested for the above question): https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57605/why-using-a-backslash-in-command-definitions

Comment: And what's the compelling reason for wanting `@footn` instead of `\footn` or, better, `\footnote`?

Comment: To paraphrase a well-loved character from a more "rural" text processing program, "It looks like you're trying to shoot yourself in the foot. Can we help?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make `@` active and define it to look ahead what the next character is. Depending on that it can insert a normal @ or expand a macro.
Please note that LaTeX's internal macro `\@ifnextchar` gobbles spaces.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\footn{\footnote}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\myAt}{%
    \@ifnextchar f
        {\expandafter \myAt@f \@gobble}%
        {@}%
}
\newcommand{\myAt@f}{%
    \@ifnextchar o
        {\expandafter \myAt@fo \@gobble}%
        {@f}%
}
\newcommand{\myAt@fo}{%
    \@ifnextchar o
        {\expandafter \myAt@foo \@gobble}%
        {@fo}%
}
\newcommand{\myAt@foo}{%
    \@ifnextchar t
        {\expandafter \myAt@foot \@gobble}%
        {@foo}%
}
\newcommand{\myAt@foot}{%
    \@ifnextchar n
        {\expandafter \footn \@gobble}%
        {@foot}%
}
\makeatother

\catcode`@=\active
\let@=\myAt

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \section{@@@}
    e-mail@footn{me@foot.com}
\end{document}
```

This kind of code is annoying to write and even more annoying if you decide to rename the command. Therefore I have written a factory command to create these commands automatically and Manuel has provided an implementation of `\ifnextchar` which does *not* gobble spaces:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\footn{\footnote}

\makeatletter
\protected\def\ifnextchar#1#2#3{%
    \let\@tmpA=#1%
    \def\@tmpB{#2}%
    \def\@tmpC{#3}%
    \futurelet\@nextToken\@doIfNextChar
} 
\def\@doIfNextChar{%
    \ifx\@nextToken\@tmpA
        \let\@doNext\@tmpB
    \else
        \let\@doNext\@tmpC
    \fi
    \@doNext
}

\newcommand{\newAlias}[2]{% #1: control sequence to define (@), #2: name
    \def\newAlias@gobbledChars{\string#1}%
    \expandafter \DeclareRobustCommand \expandafter #1\expandafter {\csname newAlias@\newAlias@gobbledChars\endcsname}%
    \newAlias@iter#2\relax
    \expandafter \let \csname newAlias@\newAlias@gobbledChars\expandafter\endcsname \csname#2\endcsname
}
\newcommand{\newAlias@iter}[1]{%
    \ifx\relax#1
        % stop
    \else
        \expandafter \edef \csname newAlias@\newAlias@gobbledChars\endcsname {%
            \unexpanded{\ifnextchar#1}%
                {\noexpand\expandafter \expandafter\noexpand\csname newAlias@\newAlias@gobbledChars#1\endcsname \noexpand\@gobble}%
                {\unexpanded\expandafter{\newAlias@gobbledChars}}%
        }%
        \expandafter \def \expandafter \newAlias@gobbledChars \expandafter {\newAlias@gobbledChars #1}%
        \expandafter \newAlias@iter
    \fi
}
\makeatother

\catcode`@=\active
\newAlias{@}{footn}

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \section{@@@}
    e-mail@footn{me@foot.com}
\end{document}
```

Please be aware that if you use hacks like these you are likely to confuse others who may read your code and possibly even yourself in future.

Comment: You could define your not space gobbling command `\protected\def\ifnextchar#1#2#3{\let\tmpa= #1\def\tmpb{#2}\def\tmpc{#3}\futurelet\nexttoken\doifnextchar} \def\doifnextchar{\ifx\nexttoken\tmpa\let\next\tmpb\else\let\next\tmpc\fi\next}`. Plus if you make use of `etoolbox` you could get much simpler definitions without `\expandafter`s (`\csedef`, `\newrobustcmd`, `\csletcs`, `\appto`, etc.). And, by the way, note that you are hardcoding `@` in `\newAlias@iter` definition.

Comment: @Manuel thank you for your comment. I have edited my answer. I have renamed the internal macros of `\ifnextchar` hoping to increase the chance of not accidentally overriding some other macro. (Is "to override" the correct word here or should it be "to overwrite"?)

Answer (score 3):

If you are free to use LuaLaTeX, the following solution may be of interest to you. It sets up a Lua function that acts as a preprocessor, scanning all input lines and replacing all instances of `@footn` with `\footnote`. By assigning the Lua function to the `process_input_buffer` callback, the work is performed before TeX starts its own work, i.e., LuaTeX never "sees" `@footn` during its own processing.

Note that there's no need to define `\footn` separately, as the Lua function directly replaces all instances of `@footn` with `\footnote`.

That said, I fail to see why writing `\footnote` might be troublesome and/or why writing `@footn` might constitute a material improvement over `\footnote`.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}

%% Lua-side code
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode}
function change_at ( s )
   return string.gsub ( s , "@footn" , "\\footnote" )
end
\end{luacode}

%% TeX-side code
\AtBeginDocument{\directlua{luatexbase.add_to_callback( 
   "process_input_buffer", change_at, "change_at" )}}

\setlength\textheight{1.5cm} % just for this example

\begin{document}
A thought.@footn{Hello, world.} 
A ``@!@?@'' thought.@footn{@Goodbye@, world.}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @AliHardan - Is there something stopping you from switching from XeLaTeX to LuaLaTeX?

Comment: @Micro, Yes. I want to use "xepersian" package and it only works in XeLaTeX. I use it for Persian language support. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using csplain, then encTeX with `\mubyte` primitive is activated. So, you can convert the byte sequence to the control sequence by:

```
\mubyte\footn @footn\endmubyte
\def\footn{SOMETHING SPECIAL}

Aha @ uff@footo, @footn, etc.

\bye
```